# Change UITableViewController's style

Tags: objective-c, tableview

How can I subsequently change the style of a `UITableView`?

Edit: Hi, i know how i set the style with the init-method, but can is change the `style` after initialization?
Like:

```
[Self.Style = "Grouped"];
```

I guess there is no way to do this, isnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay nobody seems to really read the question :D

But to answer it:
No, it can't be done, you have to re-create it

Comment: Lol...before edit que was different... And I completely missed out the SUBSEQUENTLY part!!

Answer (score 0):

```
myTVContoller = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

or

```
UITableView *myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to change the style of the whole tableview. YOu can do this by following line.

```
    UITableView *yourTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a table view style, there are two possibilities: `plain` or `grouped`.
You can set these style when you initialize the table view or when you create it on Interface Builder.
You can use something like this:

```
// Plain Style  
MyTableController *controller = [[MyTableController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];  
// Grouped Style  
MyTableController *controller = [[MyTableController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Or in IB, you can select your table view and set its style from Attribute Inspector.